# No Air for Android template on my Flash Professional CS5

Tags: android, flash, air, builder

That's about it, I've it updated, installed last adobe air version but I can't find the option or template to start a new Air for Android project. There's option for IOS, neither can I find the Mobile project option in Flash Builder. I don't have android SDK installed yet, could be this?

Comment: Have you installed the AIR SDK or AIR itself? As a developer, you really do not care about the AIR runtime as much as you do the AIR SDK (which is what is required to build AIR projects)

Comment: Ok, now that sounds obvious, already downloading it, sorry total newbie here.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded it, installed in Builder's SDK folder, clicked the adl.exe but I'm exactly as before. Thanks for your fast response Josh.

Comment: Unless you are compiling via command line, you should never have to utilize any of the files in the SDK. You need to add the SDK to Flash Pro and then try creating a new project. I have limited experience with programming in Flash Pro (I use Flash Builder/IntelliJ), so I cannot help you with setting up the SDK, unfortunately

Comment: I guess I need an extension callen Air for Android... it's a .zpx package. I hope that solves it, but still no option in Flash Builder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, now it's working on Flash Pro, but not in FB :p

Comment: Ok, I installed the Air SDK (replacing the files in ..Flash Builder 4\sdk\4.0.0 folder) and Flex SDK (same process). Now if I go to preferences it apears that Fles 4.6 SDK is installed, but still lacking the create mobile project option.